# How to use AWS CLI to spin EMR cluster for testing

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, github, command-line-interface, amazon-emr

I have made a change in python script in github and created a branch my question is how to test this using AWS CLI.

I was asked to spin up the cluster to test it please guide me the steps involved or process to follow to see the results .

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately, there is very little detail in your question, so it is hard for us to provide you any relevant information. Please edit your question to provide more details. For example, how/why do you intend to use Amazon EMR? What do you mean by "test this using AWS CLI"? What does the the Python script do? For tips on asking a good question, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty straight forward lookup from their documentation:
 1. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-spark-submit-step.html
 2. Ctrl + f for `To submit work to Spark using the AWS CLI`

For a first timer and for a one time thing, I would advice doing it in AWS EMR Web console directly.

New contributor here, please ignore the formatting of the answer.